# Use const enum keys (not values) as interface properties

Tags: typescript, enums

In following code variable `x` has properties `a` and `z`, but I want it to have `a` and `b`. How can I express that in typescript?

```
const enum CE {
    a = "a",
    b = "z",
}

declare var x: Record<CE, any> // has 'a' and 'z'
```

Comment: By not using an enum but an interface?

Comment: @maio290, I need this enum for the other purpose, but I want to have an assertion that no keys are missing.

Comment: I really admit that I don't get your usecase - and I would say that's not how you use an enum. An enum usually contains constants. So when you call enum.a it's always the same value. That's more or less their purpose. If you want CE.a to have more than one value possible, you shouldn't be using an enum.

Comment: @maio290, [some more code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgeQA4RgbwFAyHwCOMAvDAERmUA0BRYcpFlAhDfQL557AA2AQwjYAYoOBQQAJwCeMAPQAqGAEtkGfnGQIo2AEpxQ0gCYAeTBFowAFKH4AuGNGmqwAc2sA3QY5hJkACM4aQBKcgA+ZyhXDyilBVwGQmY7ED8XN08YHz8A4LCkomKYaTgoRGkwGAADABIcey4YBssAOmZmhtyuGuSYHn6mYjSMmKzvXyd8kPD8EqIyiqrahqaWnHbOjZ6+4p5Bn2lnZCgAC3J-OAB3GHFJGVkbULwjmAAPS4hTs46RykEgWAdBgABYAEyhIA) - I want to ensure that every operator has its factory method, but I want that method to have name of the key, not the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enum is variable itself, so you can query its type with `typeof CE`, then get its keys with `keyof`:

```
declare var x: Record<keyof typeof CE, any> // Record<"a" | "b", any>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgYQKIwN4CgYEwCGMAvDAEREUA0%20hARmZQF624C%20uuAJnMABsiAJzgwAbiJgAPAFwwASvxDCeAHgDWcAJ4gAZjCjaADnH3oMNYmG0A%20GAHoHQA)